# Want to update a lookup field in related object

Tags: trigger

We have case object and another custom object Clans__c, the custom object(Clan__c) is having a lookup field(Case_Number__c) to case. Here I am trying to update Case_Number__c with the case related to it and have the following code which is not working, any guess about the issue?.

```
trigger Update_clans on Case(after update) {

    set<Id> CaseIds = new set<Id>();

    map<Id, Case> mapcs = new map<Id, Case>();       

    List<clans__c> lstmpclms = new List<clans__c>();  

    for(Case cs : Trigger.New) {
         CaseIds.add(cs.Id);
         mapcs.put(cs.Id, cs);
         }        

    lstmpclms = [SELECT Name, Case_Number__c, Clan_amount__c FROM clans__c WHERE Case_Number__c IN: CaseIds];


    if(lstmpclms.size() > 0) {
        for(clans__c mpclm : lstmpclms) {
            mpclm.Case_Number__c = mapcs.get(mpclm.Id).Id;   
     //       intop.Owner__c = mapcs.get(account__c).Owner__c;
            }
        update lstmpclms;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why negative points, I am here to yearn skills.

Comment: I did not downvote this question, but I think you can improve this and future questions by providing more detail than "it is not working". We can't run your code, so we need specifics from you: *exactly* what happens or doesn't happen, what debugging effort have you done, what do your logs say, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your mapcs map returns null.

```
for(Case cs : Trigger.New) {
     CaseIds.add(cs.Id);
     mapcs.put(cs.Id, cs);
}
```

Here you are saving cs.Id (Case object Id) as key in mapcs map but you are consulting your map with an id from other object (in you care you are asking for mpclm.Id wich is the MP_Claims__c object instead of a case id).

```
lstmpclms = [SELECT Name, Case_Number__c, Claim_Amount__c, Claim_Date__c,Claim_Status__c,
              Claim_Reason__c FROM MP_Claims__c WHERE Case_Number__c IN: CaseIds];


if(lstmpclms.size() > 0) {
    for(MP_Claims__c mpclm : lstmpclms) {
        mpclm.Case_Number__c = mapcs.get(mpclm.Id).Id;   
 //       intop.Owner__c = mapcs.get(__c).Owner__c;
        }
    update lstmpclms;
}
```

if you want to get the case object stored in your mapcs map related to lstmpclms I suggest the following:

```
mpclm.Case_Number__c = mapcs.get(mpclm.Case_Number__c).Id;
```

Note: Try to change after update to before update (updating the same object type of the trigger after update could create infinite loops)